# Run perl script for files in multiple directories

Tags: macos, perl, terminal

I have multiple files (of the same name) in different subdirectories. I would like to run my perl script on all these files at once instead of have to do it individually.

For example I have the following file paths:

```
/Users/.../Documents/Results/DataSet1/Parameter1/Parameter2/data.dat
/Users/.../Documents/Results/DataSet2/Parameter1/Parameter2/data.dat
/Users/.../Documents/Results/DataSet3/Parameter1/Parameter2/data.dat
/Users/.../Documents/Results/DataSet4/Parameter1/Parameter2/data.dat
...
```

I want run my perl script on every `data.dat` file from the `Results` directory. 
Side note: I am using a Mac and would like to run the script from terminal. Right now to do each file individually I use `perl myscript.pl *.dat` for every folder.

Comment: Did you try `perl myscript.pl /Users/.../Documents/Results/DataSet*/Parameter1/Parameter2/*.dat`?

Comment: @PolarBear Yeah I tried this and it did not work

Comment: What was a message from system? Probably related to permissions. Under what account you have run the script?

Comment: All it says is Code Running..., And then nothing happens.

Comment: Do you have permission to read all these `data.dat` files? Does the script try to open any file to write result data? If it does, do you have permission to write into this directory? If you would run the script under `sudo` then these limitation will be overcome -- but be sure do not overwrite important files (do backup just in case).

Comment: You can run the script under [strace](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) to see what script is doing (of cause if `strace` is available in MacOS X).

Comment: @PolarBear using sudo does not work either

Comment: Write [bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) script to `cd` into each of these folders and run the script there as you did it earlier. But again if you do not have proper permissions then it will not be able open/write files (sudo should solve permission problem -- but if you have wrong [umask](https://linux.die.net/man/2/umask) then normal user might have issues to read result file(s) - if such file(s) created).

Comment: `myscript.pl` might be written in such way that it not able to handle filename if it includes `path` to it.

Comment: This question is missing relevant information. If you want to run a script this way you need to provide at least how the script is usually called and if it even can process multiple files on the command line. It is not even clear if you want help in running an existing script unmodified or want to modify the script so that it can handle these multiple files itself - in which case relevant parts of the code of the script are needed. For now one can only wildly speculate what you are doing and what the script can do.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is letting bash do the work for you.

```
for i in $(find /Users/.../Documents/Results -name data.dat); do (cd $(dirname $i); perl myscript.pl data.dat); done
```

Comment: Isn't `dir=dirname $i` easier/better?

Comment: Yes, probably - I haven't used it though.

Comment: Also if you run the inside of the `for` loop in a sub-shell you won't need to `cd` *back*.  You're welcome!

Comment: thats true because /User.. is an absolute path. Otherwise I need to get back, because the path might only be relative to my position. There are other solutions, but cd - might be the easiest.

Comment: It doesn't matter if `/User` is absolute at all; this is simply better: `for i in $(find /Users/.../Documents/Results -name data.dat); do (cd $(dirname $i); perl myscript.pl data.dat); done;`.

Comment: oh, I wasn't aware you could create a 'sub-shell' by simply putting the body into parenthesis. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of threads and glob with perl, like this:

```perl
use threads;

my $basepath = '/Users/.../Documents/Results';
my @files = glob qq("${basepath}/DataSet?/Parameter?/Parameter?/data.dat");

threads->create(\&processdata, $_) for @files;

sub processdata {
    my $file = shift;
    # do your processing here
}
```

This starts a distinct thread for each data.dat file found by the glob.